# Unable to send email from HVS work queue

Tags: high-velocity-sales, sales-cadence

I finished setting up HVS with all the steps from the implementation guide. I created a test sales cadence with 1 manual email action. I added a lead to it and when I am trying to send that manual email from the work queue I am seeing this error message

“No global or entity specific email actions are registered for this entity”

Can y’all please help me with the steps to resolve this?

Comment: Try positing in this Success Community https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F93A0000009WKhSAM

Answer (score 1):

If you have email deliverability set to System Only or No Access, you'll receive this error when attempting to send an email.  If you change your deliverability to All email, you should be able to complete this test.